# Is it possible to recompile subversion without deleting current repository in CentOS?

Tags: svn, centos5

i want to recompile to enable http checkout
after i install neon

```
yum install neon-devel
```

then i make compile

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-apxs=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-apr=/usr/bin/apr-config 
make
make install
```

when i reinstall it delete all my data in repository,
how can i recompile svn to enable neon plugin without delete my current data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would reinstalling delete your data?  That is not normal.

You shouldn't have to do anything to your data.  So long as we are assuming you are going to be installing a version of subversion that is the same version or newer.  Downgrading is where you might run into issues.

If you do not already have a backup, then you should first take the time to run `svnadmin dump`, which will give up a full backup.  If your data is lost, then restore it.

Comment: Maybe the author has had to use Visual Source Safe in the past? ;)